# At what energy consumption would we get a 1 degree rise in the Earth's temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, geophysics

If energy consumption continues to rise at (say) 4% per year, how long before the heat dissipation seriously impacts climate?

Comment: Try cbat.info :)

Comment: I think that probably the most productive approach would be to compare this heat dissipation to geothermal heat generation (which is around 0.1 W/m²), as it is of similar nature (a more or less constant internal heat source).

Answer (score 1):

Q=mc(t1-t2)
You need to calculate C, the specific heat capacity of Earth(as a whole).
You need to calculate the specific heat capacity of everything present on, inside earth for that purpose. 
It might be possible after we advance a bit more further:).

Answer (score 1):

- [Global energy consumption](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=global%20energy%20consumption%20in%20joules) is $5\times10^{20}\ J/yr$
- Assume it is all used to power incandescent lightbulbs, so [95% goes to heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Efficacy.2C_efficiency.2C_and_environmental_impact) the atmosphere
- The [mass of the atmosphere](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mass%20of%20the%20atmosphere) is $5\times10^{18}\ kg$
- The [heat capacity of air](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=heat%20capacity%20of%20air) is $1\times10^{3}\frac{J}{kg\cdot °C}$

Assuming all the heat goes to the atmosphere and stays there, using the definition of heat capcity $C$:

$$Q = mC \Delta T$$
$$\Delta T = \frac{Q}{mC}=\frac{\left(95\%\right)\left(5\times10^{20}\ J/yr\right)}{\left(5\times10^{18}\ kg\right)\left(1\times10^{3}\frac{J}{kg\cdot °C}\right)} = 0.095 °C/yr$$

To answer your question about a rise of 4% let's calculate how many years it would take before the atmosphere was heating at 1 °C/yr... oh [compound interest formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Simplified_calculation), how I've missed you:

$$n=\frac{ln(FV)-ln(PV)}{ln(1+i)}=\frac{ln(1)-ln(0.095)}{ln(1+0.04)}=60$$

In other words, if the rate of energy consumption goes up at 4% per year and nearly all that energy ends up as heat (using lightbulbs as a model), in **60 years the atmosphere would heat up at 1 °C/yr**. Please note these calculations are *extremely* naive and have little bearing on reality in that they ignore 1) factors that actually control the climate, such as gas composition, greenhouse effect, transfer of heat between air-oceans-land, feedback mechanisms, etc. 2) the economics of steady 4% energy consumption increase 3) the fraction of energy consumption that heats the atmosphere.

Comment: You have to consider the oceans.

Comment: @gerrit right. The unstated assumption was that heat goes to the atmosphere and stays there. I added it explicitly to the post, thanks.

Comment: Right.  That assumption is very very far from the real world, so your calculation is interesting, but not very useful.  As you already state in your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to compare human produced heat with the incident heat of the sun which is around 1 kW/m$^2$. The usual comparison is "the sun delivers more heat in an hour than humans use in a day". While such a comparison may not remain accurate forever, a difference in scale of 7000x suggests that even if humans doubled thei energy consumption every 17 years (Thalys roughly 4% per year) it would be w hole before we compete with the sun. This suggests that direct heating of Earth by human activity is insignificant.

But the extent to which human activity can change (even by a small %) the amount of sunlight captured by the atmosphere is a MUCH bigger deal. If we would cause just 1% more of the sun's power to remain on earth (by slightly modifying the surface properties of Earth or the atmospheric composition) that is a far more powerful multiplier. This is why there is such emphasis on greenhouse gas emissions.